# SSRS Expression Lookup and Max are not working together

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression, lookup

```
= MAX(LookupSet("SR Light Naphtha",Fields!DISPLAY_NAME.Value, Fields!Max.Value, "LIMS_VALUES"))
```

gives error at the report UI after I deployed the report.

Below is the data set that returns value. I need to get MIN(Min) and MAX(MAX).

With the below dataset, result for max should be 120. But it displays error at the report UI.

[image]

[image: Data Set]

Answer (score 1):

The `lookupset` function returns an object that contains all the values that the lookup found.  As the `max` function requires a column of values and you are giving it an object, this means you are trying to do something with `max` that `max` is not actually able to do.

To find the `max` of all the values returned in the `lookupset`, you will need to add some Custom Code to your report and then pass the result of the `lookupset` to that Custom Code.

Within the Custom Code, write a for each loop that iterates through the values of the `lookupset` and retains the largest, outputting whatever value is left at the end of the loop.  This value will be the maximum value that you are after.

[This documentation from Microsoft shows how to write your Custom Code to loop through the results of a `lookupset`, albeit to output HTML.  You should be able to pretty readily replace the innards of that function to return the min, max or other aggregates like a sum for your own requirements.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookupset-function?view=sql-server-ver15)

Example code in case of link rot:

```
=LookupSet(Fields!SourceMatchCol.Value, Fields!TargetMatchCol.Value, Fields!ReturnCol.Value, "Dataset")
```

```
Function LookupSetMax(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
  If items Is Nothing Then
    Return Nothing
  End If

  Dim maxValue as Decimal = Decimal.MinValue
   
  For Each item As Object In items
    If thisItemAsDecimal > currentMax Then currentMax = thisItemAsDecimal
  Next
   
  Return maxValue
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your search value is hard coded, you can just use a MAX over the dataset with an IIF:

```
= MAX(IIF(Fields!DISPLAY_NAME.Value = "SR Light Naphtha", Fields!Max.Value, NOTHING) "LIMS_VALUES")


= MIN(IIF(Fields!DISPLAY_NAME.Value = "SR Light Naphtha", Fields!Min.Value, NOTHING) "LIMS_VALUES")
```